# JQUERY Creating a sliding effect while image is changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, html

I have three images 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg & `<img id="add" src="1.jpg"></img>` the width , Height & position of this image is set as required & working fine. I have applied JQUERY fade property to toggle between the above images & its also working fine.

But I want precisely that the images change in sliding fashion, i.e. 1.jpg slides left and vanishes and drags in 2.jpg in its position & so on continues in specific interval.

Hope I am clear...

Regards.

Comment: Share what you attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yhank You everyone for your efforts, But , I configured it myself... Here is how it worked:

index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="slide.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div >
        <img id="pic1" src="1.jpg"style="width:0px;height:120px;"/><img id="pic2" src="2.jpg" style="width:160px;height:120px;"/>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

slide.js

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var img_l=$("#pic1");
    var img_r=$("#pic2");
    setInterval(function(){
        img_l.animate({width:'160px'},1000);;    //animating the image t colapse
        img_r.animate({width:'0px'},1000);;      //animating the image t expand
        var temp_var=img_l;                      //swaping values to revert previous action
        img_l=img_r;
        img_r=temp_var;
    },3000);                                    //repeating the effect every 3 seconds
});
```

This is doing well with my requirements and has exactly same behaviour within all leading browsers...
Thanks.